# Include windows office 2010 ribbon bar for C# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, office-2010

I just needed to include windows office 2010 Ribbon bar into my C# application(Not WPF)..
So i search it on a internet but i cant find any solution...

I need a free solution for creating this ribbon bar...

Thank you..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206370/the-best-ribbon-interface-library

Comment: its Winform applicatio... is there any possibility...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try the one offered by [componentfactory.com](http://componentfactory.com).

Comment: The Componentfactory ribbon is a ribbon component for WinForms with Office 2010 look, so my answer is totally correct. Downvoting would make sense if I gave a *wrong* answer - just the fact that it isn't the accepted answer doesn't require a downvote...

Comment: Ohh.. no.. sorry about that sir.. im new in this stackoverflow.. so i dont know how this thing work.. i just click on that.. so i just beg your pardon..

Comment: Ah, I see. You can undo your downvote if you want by simply pressing the "up"-arrow once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use devcomponents-dotnetbar ribben control. 
Just google on dotnetbar ribben control.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using this one?

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25907/A-Professional-Ribbon-You-Will-Use-Now-with-orb

Comment: This implementation does not provide Office 2010 look.